# (R, quantreg): Hypothesis testing a large range of quantiles

Tags: r, quantreg

I have a quantile regression model with 1 regressor and 1 regressand. I want to hypothesis test that the regressor is equal over every quantile. One approach I've thought of is to test over all tau over {0.01,0.02,....,0.99}. However, I would then have to write:

`anova(model1,model2,model3,.......,model99)`, where each model corresponds to a different tau. **Question: How do I get anova() to accept large amount of models of type `rq` without manually typing them out?**

---

My attempt at a solution has been to do this:

```
y = rnorm(100)
x = rnorm(100)

rqs_object <- rq(y~x,tau=1:99/100)
anova(rqs_object)
```

However, `anova` clearly doesn't take object type `rqs`, only type `rq`, unfortunately.

---

Cross posted [here](http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/27704-Hypothesis-testing-multiple-quantiles-in-quantile-regression-%28quantreg-package%29) until I decided that it had a large programming/specialist element to the problem .

Comment: You should not ask multiple questions at once.

Comment: Ok I didn't know that. I'll delete the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I concentrate on question 1 and only on the programming part.

some data:

```
set.seed(65465)
y = rnorm(100)
x = rnorm(100)
```

Now I define a function, that takes tau as input and does the fit:

```
rqfits <- function(tau) {
  require(quantreg)
  rq(y~x,tau=tau)
}
```

I can then apply this function on a vector of taus:

```
taus <- 1:5/10
fits <- lapply(taus,rqfits)
```

The result is a list of models. 
We can now use `do.call` to pass our models to `anova`:

```
do.call(anova,fits)

Quantile Regression Analysis of Deviance Table

Model: y ~ x
Joint Test of Equality of Slopes: tau in {  0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5  }

  Df Resid Df F value Pr(>F)
1  4      496  1.0388 0.3866
Warning:
In summary.rq(x, se = se, covariance = TRUE) : 2 non-positive fis
```

Comment: @user1125946  I edited my answer, because I just remembered that `do.call` exists.